# Is the time around 4th July a period of high demand for motel accomodation in the USA?

Tags: usa, accommodation

I'm thinking of doing an unplanned roadtrip in the Pacific northwest next month from July 4-7th. I haven't decided exactly where.

Normally in the US I'm happy doing this without booking places to stay, because there are always motels. But possibly with July 4th, more people will be travelling. Is this the case? Do motels etc tend to fill up at this time of year?

Comment: This question is unanswerable in the current form as there is a difference between a motel in the back blocks of Montana vs a motel within walking distance of the Mall at Washington DC, and we have no clue where you are located or where you plan to drive.

Comment: Avoid beaches, lakes, and national parks, since these are the places people tend to go on holiday. Some cities like NYC or DC (as mentioned in the comment by @PeterM) will also be crowded, but probably no more so than any other time in the summer.

Comment: Eh, well, the unanswerable question has a useful answer :-) @MikeHarris's comment would also have made a helpful answer.

Comment: @Flyto As worded, the question is asking "do travel accommodations fill up during periods of peak demand for travel accommodations?" It might be salvageable if rephrased, but otherwise I don't understand how it is useful.

Comment: @choster there's an unstated assumption in your comment, which suggests how the question might be edited to be more acceptable to some. I'll give it a shot...

Comment: If I were you, I'd invest a few minutes each night deciding where I was planning on going the next day, and trying to book a place for the following night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they do.  Last year I drove from Austin, TX to Atlanta, GA over 4th of July and starting in Dallas we tried to find a motel/hotel in every city along the way.  All were booked up.  We finally found one in East Mississippi at 2:00am.